# Ctrl-r do not run when the build directory has been changed

Tags: qt, qt-creator

By default the build directory of a project is a sibling, withing the same directory than the project himself.

To have a better organisation in my backup process, I have moved the defaut build path in a directory which is sibling of the parent directory of all my projects. The compilation default path has been updated accordingly.

Now I only backup my projects, without the builds.

The problem I'm facing now is about the execute key combo Ctrl-r for which I get the compilation progress bar, but in fact, the project is not compiled now. This is confirmed because the compiled files do not update within the buid directory.

The only way, now, to update compilation is through the menu Build-> build all. It works but without key binding and I need after to execute.

Is there a way to recover Ctrl-r when changing the build directory path ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

When you run a project from Qt Creator, it gets rebuilt only if needed, as clearly stated [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-building-running.html):

> Run configurations start the application in the location where it was
>   copied by the deploy configuration. By default, when you select the
>   Run function, Qt Creator builds the project, deploys it to the device
>   defined in the kit, and runs it there. However, ***if you have not made
>   any changes to the project since you last built and deployed it, Qt
>   Creator simply runs it again***.

The only way to force build is to issue the rebuild command explicitely (you can use the **Ctrl-B** shortcut for that purpose).

If the default build directory is changed (in *Tools>Options>Build & Run>General*) this setting will apply (as a default) for subsequently created projects. Existing projects will keep their build directory, as specified in the project Build Settings.

You may also want to check if the options

- Always build project before deploying it
- Always deploy project before running it

in *Tools>Options>Build & Run>General* are set.

Sometimes, editing a header file does not trigger a build, even if the file is included in some *cpp* file. To solve this issue in Qt Creator, just add a line like this to the *pro* file:

```
DEPENDPATH += path/to/the/header(s)
```

Comment: I agree : "If you have not made any changes". But if you did it, the Run fonction builds again the project. That is the problem ! When changing the build directory, It shows it does by displaying the progress bar, but really, it doesn't... Try a simple project like "hello world". If you change it, says "hello me" - the build path being changed in another directory, when actionning the run fonction you'll see you get "hello world" and not "hello me", because of the path changed.

Comment: Yes again. The default build directory is updated to the correct directory. No matter with that. But, finally, it does not work as it would be. Even with the F5 fonction (begin debug). Thanks for your help.

Comment: You must check the build directory in project settings, not the default build directory in Tools>Options>etc

Comment: Again, yes, it is ok. The build directory in project settings is exactly the same than the default one. And if you create a new project, both are the same by default. So the root cause is not a directory assignement. It's a wrong way to look at this side. Another test I conducted. If I empty the build directory before running F5 or ctrl-r, then it populates with the new recompiled files. If the previous files remain, they are not overwritten by the rebuild. I do not understand it and I'm looping around this problem. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Check the options I added at the end of the answer.

Comment: And the timestamp issue (which I think is the only possible explanation, by now).

Comment: Thanks paolo. The two options are set. Could you develop a little bit more the process to check the timestamp ?

Comment: I just removed the timestamp issue: in that case the build wouldn't work as well, but you say it does. Does it?

Comment: I does if I remove the old files from the build/debug directory before launching F5 or Ctrl-r. It does not otherwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162816/discussion-between-p-a-o-l-o-and-kontiki).

Comment: reported as a bug to Qt here : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-19577

Comment: Well done. BTW, I would try setting the build path without the % variables, i.e. c:/some_path/test

Comment: No more success without % nor without variables %{CurrentProject:Name}-%{CurrentKit:FileSystemName}-%{CurrentBuild:Name}